# Get line function after mapping one x|y 2D space to another x|y 2D space

Tags: vector-spaces

I am not a mathematician, so sorry for my poor dictionary.
I have a mapping function of a form:
$$f(x,y,w) = \begin{cases}x':\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\y':\sqrt{w^{2} - 2wx + x^{2} + y^{2}}\end{cases}$$
where x,y - coordinates of original space, and w - is width of this space.

That visually looks like here:
[image]

My final goal is to be able to convert SVG path tag from one space to another. So I am thinking is that possible at all? Can I get some nice curved line formula for each line in original space?

What are the keywords should I be looking for?

Here is a video of this space mapping in dynamic - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zxOiLNp9tU